# When to use Entity and when DTO?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, entity, apache-beam

So I'm working with Apache beam with SpringBoot, and with JDBCIO in .query I'm retrieving records from table "customer" (select * from records.customer where customer_code = "abc").So this "customer" class should be an entity or a DTO ?

My understanding is we need an entity only when we are working with repositories. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You would use an `Entity` while dealing with a JPA Repository. The thing to keep in mind is that an `Entity` is basically a representation of your Database and thus, for example with Hibernate (a JPA implementation), every change you in an `Entity` data will be at some point persisted in the database. This might be exactly what you need and want or maybe it is not and you must be cautious. Imagine that you share `Entities` between two different `Service` classes and one of them make changes to it, effectively having side-effects. This is usually a source of bugs.

A DTO (Data Transfer Object) is usually used to expose your `Entities` via a REST API. If you would use `Entity` itself, you might get in trouble when Jackson tries to serialize the object to JSON. You might as well see code that actually uses DTOs to communicated between `Services`. This usually reduces the possibility of bugs (as described earlier) but it also makes your code more complex and might make it hard to achieve some use cases.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. I am just wondering how we can run into trouble when Jackson tries to serialize an entity. I would love to hear more about this.

Comment: The thing is that when Jackson tries to serialize the object it will need all the objects associated with it. Imagine that you have an object of Class A with an attribute of Class B that is modeled in a different table. If your association is lazy (meaning that you will not get all the object graph when you query your database, but only when you require it) you might face issues when Jackson tries to serialise the object of Class A, because by then you might not be able to get the things you need from the database because the session for that request is gone.

Comment: You can find additional details here --> https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-exceptions#initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You could use either one of them depending on your domain.
Entities are used to go with your domain scope. It applies "behavior".
DTO(Data Transfer Object) are used to transfer data from one process/module to a another.